# What is forcing inline styles in my markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this is totally gonna get downvoted, because although I think is a legitimate concern and I'm sure other people have them, it's a "codeless" question. :) Hopefully I get an answer before it gets on hold.

I always make sure not to use unnecessary inline styles. But today I noticed, there is a script forcing inline styles in my markup and I can't smoke it out. I will provide my website link at request (I don't wanna come off like I'm fishing for traffic), that way you can see it but basically what happens is my website loads fine, then after I hover or click on a certain element, an inline style magically appears.

Here's some visual aid

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: In the elements tab, select the element in question, right click and pick "break on attribute modifications", that should show you where it's coming from

Comment: There is most likely javascript acting on the button and applying styles.

Comment: @MattGreer Great tip! Make it an answer and I'll upvote it. It helped me find the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, whenever you use jQuery to apply styles, it applies them inline, to the `style=""` attribute. Check your jQuery for the "mystery styles" that you are having trouble with. The `grep` command is your friend.

Good luck!

Comment: interesting. I'll go check that out and come back

Comment: Matt's tip to find the culprit helped me realize it was the animation.min.js causing this. But good point on the JQuery adding styles to the affected element Thanks!